# Servletconfig cannot be resolved to a type and ServletConfig , this.conf are marked as error

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

[image]
As you can see many parts of program are marked red, i tried to make it all right but i couldn't could anyone please help

Comment: Replace javax with jakarta

Comment: its still not solving the error

Comment: Can you provide the included libraries?